# Spring mvc Hibernate Integration

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

How to integrate hibernateUtil and hibernate.cgf.xml in spring mvc? Witch XML file should I make the configuration dao-context.xml or store-servlet.xml?   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEdnx.png)

Store-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.web.controller"></context:component-scan>
    <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>

    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

dao-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">


    <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.web.dao"></context:component-scan>

</beans>
```

service-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">


    <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.web.service">
    </context:component-scan>
</beans>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">COMPTE</property>
        <property name="connection.username">compte</property>
        <property name="connection.password">compte</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property> 

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <!-- Importante pour la creation a zero "create" / "update" de table -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

        <!-- Names the annotated entity class -->
        <mapping class="com.web.dao.User"/> 
        <mapping class="com.web.dao.Ville"/>
        <mapping class="com.web.dao.Compte"/>

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

HibernateUtil.java

```
package com.web.util;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static{
        try {
            sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
            //sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutDown(){
        //closes caches and connections
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to integrate hibernateUtil and hibernate.cgf.xml in spring mvc?

- **hibernate.cfg.xml**:This is the main hibernate configuration file for loading the database configuration and mapping files for the entities. This must be the classpath location inside your project. By default hibernate would look for the root of the classpath directory. If you want to use the different location, you have to pass the location to the config object at the time of loading the configurations.And here you have to define the database details and mapping files locations.
- **hibernateUtil**: Actually, There is no integration for this class in spring mvc.So It is a simple way to implement a DAO and to control Hibernate sessions and transactions manually.